# Sorting with two vectors

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm wondering if it's possible if you have, for example, a `vector<string>` and a `vector<double>` with corresponding pairs, to sort the `vector<string>` alphabetically while keeping the pairs matched up.

I know this can be done by creating a class that holds both values and just sorting that, but I'd rather keep two separate vectors.

Any ideas?

Final Code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

struct Name_pairs
{
       vector<string>names;
       vector<double>ages;
       void quicksort(vector<string>& num, vector<double>& num2, int top, int bottom);
       int divide(vector<string>& array, vector<double>& array2, int top, int bottom);
       bool test();
       string read_names();
       double read_ages();
       void print();
};

string Name_pairs::read_names()
{
       string name;
     cout << "Enter name: ";
     cin >> name;
     names.push_back(name);
     return name;
}

double Name_pairs::read_ages()
{
     double age;
     cout << "Enter corresponding age: ";
     cin >> age;
     ages.push_back(age);
     cout << endl;
     return age;
}

int Name_pairs::divide(vector<string>& array, vector<double>& array2, int top, int bottom)
{
    string x = array[top];
    int i = top-1;
    int j = bottom+1;
    string temp;
    double temp2;
    do{
        do
        {
             j--;
             }while(x<array[j]);

        do
        {
             i++;
             }while(x>array[i]);

        if(i<j)
        {
               temp = array[i];
               temp2 = array2[i];
               array[i] = array[j];
               array2[i] = array2[j];
               array[j] = temp;
               array2[j] = temp2;
               }
               }while(i<j);
        return j;
}


void Name_pairs::quicksort(vector<string>& num, vector<double>& num2, int top, int bottom) // top is subscript of beginning of vector
{
     int middle;
     if(top < bottom)
     {
            middle = divide(num, num2, top, bottom);
            quicksort(num, num2, top, middle);
            quicksort(num, num2, middle+1, bottom);
            }
     return;
}

void Name_pairs::print()
{
     for(int i = 0; i < (names.size()-1) && i < (ages.size()-1); ++i)
             cout << names[i] << " , " << ages[i] << endl;
}

int main(){
    Name_pairs np;
    cout << "Enter names and ages. Use 0 to cancel.\n";
    bool finished = false;
    while(!finished){
    finished = "0" == np.read_names();
    finished = 0 == np.read_ages();}
    np.quicksort(np.names, np.ages, 0, (np.names.size()-2));
    np.print();
    keep_window_open();}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you use two vectors rather than a more complex data structure?

Comment: Learning from a book and it was the exercise's intention. Haven't even learned about maps or arrays yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to use std::sort, you will need to use a datastructure like a pair.
You can, of course, manually sort the vectors, and essentially reimplement std::sort.

This question really depends on a great number of other questions, such as:

- How many items will be in the vectors?
- How critical is performance?
- Do you REALLY want to implement your own sort algorithm?

Implementing a quicksort should be fairly painless, and will allow you to avoid moving the data around.

Comment: Hmmm. What about somehow synchronizing the vectors so whatever happens to the index of one happens to the index of the other.

Comment: The problem is that synchronisation. std::sort doesn't allow for it, so you'd have to implement your own sort.

Comment: Hmmm....I looked at the sort member in <algorithm> and it doesn't look like I'll be able to borrow anything from that. Any ideas?

Comment: If you really want to do this, implement a quicksort, or, if performance is not an issue, a bubblesort, keeping both vectors in sync.

Comment: If you are learning the language, implementing a sort is always an excellent exercise, in order to familiarise yourself.

Comment: Alright thanks, sounds like a fun little mini-project (I hope!).

Answer (score 5):

If you manually sort them yourself, you can just swap the corresponding items in the double array along with the items in the string array that you would normally do. Or, you could have a third array:

```
vector<unsigned int> indices;
```

That just indexes into the string/double array, and sort that array instead (swapping based on the values in the string array).

Comment: No, I'm not sorting each object individually. There is potentially too much data for that. I'm intrigued by your second idea though, but how can it index both a string and a double? Wouldn't I have to create a class for that?

Comment: No - an index is just a number. The idea is very feasible. You create a vector<size_t> indices; and then pass a custom ordering to std::sort that compares myDoubles[indices[i]] instead of indices[i]. You'll then end up with an ordering of indices[i] such that myDoubles[indices[i]] < myDoubles[indices[i+1]]. You can then remove this indirection by setting mySortedDoubles[i] = myDoubles[indices[i]];

Answer (score 4):

Although the indices idea is effectively the same, you can in fact define a random access iterator type that knows the two vectors, and moves them (through assignment) in sync.  The value_type of that iterator would be pair.  In functional programming, you'd call this a "zip" (but not a zipper).

It's definitely not worth the hassle unless you're VERY tight on space.  If you have the space, actually zipping the two vectors into a single vector of pairs, or using the indices approach, are both easier.

If you're able to get it right the first time, copy/pasting a 10 line quicksort with the obvious modifications will be the fastest way to what you want.

---

***Ed's note:*** there is an already-written [Zip Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) available in Boost, as pointed out in this newer answer to the same question: ["Locking" two vectors and sorting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147911/locking-two-vectors-and-sorting-them-c/8148027#8148027)

Comment: Exactly the iterator I was going to suggest, except that I probably would have forgotten to mention zip, and I was going to add, "I really cannot be bothered to go to the hassle of providing you with a tested example implementation" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could create an auxiliary vector:

```
vector<unsigned int> indices;
```

Initialize it to to `0,1,2,...n-1`, where `n` is the size of your vectors, and have the `sort` algorithm sort it using a functor that looks at the `vector<string>`, i.e., when asked to compare index1 and index2, the functor will look up the corresponding strings and compare them instead.  Once you have `indices` sorted, you can easily sort your two arrays to conform to it in linear time.

**Edit:** I didn't see Jim Buck's second suggestion.  My answer is just an expanded version of that.