# "Locking" two vectors and sorting them

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have this two `vector<double>` 's `mass` and `velocity` both of the same size `N`. They contain the information about the mass and velocity of N particles. `mass[i]` and `velocity[i]` are thus properties of the i'th particle

Is it possible in C++ to "lock" these two vectors together and sort them in increasing order of mass? 
Thus after the sorting the vector `mass` should be in increasing order, and the velocity vector should contain the corresponding velocities of the sorted masses

e.g. Before sorting mass = (4,2,1,3) and velocity = (13, 14,15,16 )
     After sorting mass=(1,2,3,4) and velocity =(15, 14, 16, 13)

The one (non-efficient) way I know for this is to transfer the data into an vector of struct's

```
struct particle
{

double mass;
double velocity;


bool operator < (const particle& str) const

 {
    return (mass < str.mass);
  }



};
```

and create `vector<particle> particlelist(N)` and then sort this vector by using the `std::sort` by overloading the `<` operator as I have done in the definition above.

I do not want to put my data into Array of Structures fashion since I have heard it is inefficient compared to the Structure of Arrays approach(at least in CUDA).

Comment: define "lock" better do you mean like if one changes a property the other changes i the same manner?

Comment: I have made the edit and clarified the question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398819/sort-by-proxy-or-sort-one-container-by-the-contents-of-another-in-c

Comment: `sort(zip(mass.all(), velocity.all()))` if we had Alexandrescu's ranges :)

Comment: Regarding efficiency -- it depends on your data access patterns. If processing a particle involves looking at both mass and velocity, then both values will have to be read from memory at once, in which case it is advantageous to load them both into the cache simultaneously (i.e., use array-of-structs). If you have two separate processing passes, one which only looks at mass and one which only looks at velocity, then struct-of-arrays is likely to be better so that each process can make most effective use of cache memory and not have half of it wasted by an irrelevant value.

Comment: (of course the above is just a rule-of-thumb guideline -- there are other factors involved too; as always, to know true performance you have to measure it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least as far as I know, none of the sorting algorithms built into the standard library will do this for you directly. The most obvious possibility would probably be to use a Boost [Zip Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) to make the two arrays act like a single collection.

Answer (score 10):

Create vector indexes; fill it by values 0..n-1 than

```
    struct CmpMass {
    {
       CmpMass(vector<double>& vec) : values(vec){}
       bool operator() (const int& a, const int& b) const
       {
           return values[a] < values[b];
       }
       vector<double>& values;
    }

sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), CmpMass(mass));
```

than you have in vector indexes order of items in both arrays. Than you can create mass/velocity vectors in correct order or convert index during access: mass[indexes[i]], velocity[indexes[i]]

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use [`std::pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/) as you have two values which are linked, you than can then implement your own comparison method/function to pass on to the `std::sort` function via pointer(there exist an overloaded version of [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) which supports that).

But be sure that you have a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) implemented, because else `std::sort` might lead to a `SEGFAULT`